# Why does SFAuthenticationSession consent alert show Xcode project name instead of App name?

Tags: ios, ios11, sfauthenticationsession

I'm using `SFAuthenticationSession` to authenticate via `OAuth2`.

The consent the user has to agree displays the following message as an alert:

> "[Xcode-Project-Name]" Wants to Use "[Server-URL]" to Sign In. This allows the app and website to share information about you.

Why isn't the App Display Name being mentioned?

Will it be the App name after App Store submission?

Comment: +1 on this. You can change the Product Name in Build Settings, but the module name it compiles to is this name too, which screws up module imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFAuthenticationSession uses Product name for App Store apps too. It is deprecated in iOS 12 in favor of the new ASWebAuthenticationSession. Let's hope it is fixed to use app Display name instead.